# Htaccess redirect loop when using WWW in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on making my site's urls pretty for SEO but I am coming across the problem that when going to 'obliquedev.x10.mx' the site displays fine but when going to 'www.obliquedev.x10.mx' I get a redirect loop error.

Error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeMJ3.png

This is my .htaccess in the root of my site :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ Public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) Public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is the .htaccess in Root/Public :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to exclude `Public` from being rewritten

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Public
RewriteRule ^.*$ /Public/$0 [L]
```

You also don't need two rules, this one rule covers both cases.

Comment: Sorry, I am very confused. How would I write the RewriteCond? I don't know the syntax of Apache htaccess. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay, the first RewriteRule was a typo, my bad. Although it still throws the error.